# c++ How Can I Achieve This Class Structure?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, cross-platform

I'm racking my brain trying to find out how to write cross platform classes while avoiding the cost of virtual functions and any kind of ugliness in the platform specific versions of classes. Here is what I have tried.

**PlatformIndependantClass.hpp**

```
class PlatformIndependantClass {
    public:
        PlatformIndependantClass();
        std::string GetPlatformName();
    private:
        PlatformIndependantClass* mImplementation;

};
```

**LinuxClass.hpp**

```
#include "PlatformIndependantClass.hpp"
class LinuxClass : public PlatformIndependantClass{
    public:
        std::string GetPlatformName();
};
```

**WindowsClass.hpp**

```
#include "PlatformIndependantClass.hpp"
class WindowsClass : public PlatformIndependantClass {
    public:
        std::string GetPlatformName();
};
```

**PlatformIndependantClass.cpp**

```
#include "PlatformIndependantClass.hpp"
#include "LinuxClass.hpp"
#include "WindowsClass.hpp"
PlatformIndependantClass::PlatformIndependantClass() {
    #ifdef TARGET_LINUX
        mImplementation = new LinuxClass();
    #endif
    #ifdef TARGET_WINDOWS
        mImplementation = new WindowsClass();
    #endif
}
std::string PlatformIndependantClass::GetPlatformName() {
    return mImplementation->GetPlatformName();
}
```

**LinuxClass.cpp**

```
#include "LinuxClass.hpp"
std::string LinuxClass::GetPlatformName() {
    return std::string("This was compiled on linux!");
}
```

**WindowsClass.cpp**

```
#include "WindowsClass.hpp"
std::string WindowsClass::GetPlatformName() {
    return std::string("This was compiled on windows!");
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "PlatformIndependantClass.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    PlatformIndependantClass* cl = new PlatformIndependantClass();
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    cout << "Operating system name is: " << cl->GetPlatformName() << endl;
    cout << "Bye!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Now, this compiles fine but I get a segmentation fault. I believe this is because the platform specific classes inherit from PlatformIndependantClass, which on construction, creates an instance of the platform specific class, so I get infinite recursion. Every time I try, I just get extremely confused!

How can I achieve a design like this properly? Or is this just a horrible idea. I have been trying to find out how to write cross platform classes but I just get a load of results about cross platform libraries, any help will be gratefully accepted :)

Comment: What do you mean by "platform indenpendence"?

Comment: How much do the virtual functions cost - and is this enough for the users to notice?

Comment: PS: "independent" doesn't have an "a" in it.

Comment: @NedBatchelder Thank you, I will change in my code :)

Comment: @Mark I know you may think that this is premature optimization, but it is more of a learning exercise.

Comment: @R.Martinho Fernandes as in, abstracts the platform specific code away.

Comment: @Ell: That's what conditional compilation is for. You'll need conditional compilation anyway with your scheme.

Comment: Long ago someone came up with the Pimpl idiom. Then everyone lived happily ever after. Or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you are trying to accomplish can be accomplished much easier...

Object.h:

```
#include <normal includes>

#if WINDOWS
#include <windows includes>
#endif

#if LINUX
#include <linux includes>
#endif

class Object
{
private:

#if WINDOWS
//Windows Specific Fields...
#endif

#if LINUX
//Linux Specific Fields...
#endif

public:
    //Function that performs platform specific functionality
    void DoPlatformSpecificStuff();

    //Nothing platform specific here
    void DoStuff();      
};
```

Object.cpp

```
#include "Object.h"

void Object::DoStuff() { ... }
```

ObjectWin32.cpp

```
#if WINDOWS

#include "Object.h"

void Object::DoPlatformSpecificStuff() 
{ 
    //Windows specific stuff... 
}

#endif
```

ObjectLinux.cpp

```
#if LINUX

#include "Object.h"

void Object::DoPlatformSpecificStuff() 
{ 
    //Linux specific stuff... 
}

#endif
```

And so on.  I think this could accomplish what you are trying in a bit easier fashion.  Also, no virtual functions needed.

Comment: +1, beats the hell out of my multiple library idea, I've been away from C++ for too long :)

Comment: @Blindy: Sometimes I wish to get away from C++ for a while, but I always come back... :-)

Comment: This would require platform specific header files as well wouldn't it? For the private members? I would like to separate the headers into different files instead of littering it with preprocessor directives, how would I go about doing that with this approach?

Comment: I was goint to show code that separates the public class from the implemtation class, but then it dawned on me that you just do what James says, i.e., put all the implementation-specific code into separate platform-specific source files, and just share the same header file. Simple.

Comment: @Ell: Updated the answer.  You can have platform-specific fields defined in the header, wrapped with #if or #ifdef.

Comment: I would much rather have separate header files but I think this might be the easiest way to go :/

Comment: @Ell: I use this 'pattern' all the time when writing cross-platform C++ stuff, and it is much easier than the other methods I have tried. Good luck!

Comment: This can also be done abstracting all OS-specific stuff out of the headers (as in my answer), but at a slight performance cost.

Comment: @Eli: why would you want seperate headers files?  I'd think you'd want to be sure that the object's functionality is unchanged from one OS to another, which is assured by a shared header.

Comment: Well, I would want to have separate header files for data members but a unified header for public interface, that is why I initially thought of inheritance. I think I might end up doing what you suggest with the header file, and then use my build system for compiling the source. Would you say that is a sensible approach?

Comment: If you wish, you can hold onto a `void*` that points to platform specific data.  This `void*` can then be initialized to point to all data needed inside the platform-specific constructor defined in the platform specific implementation file.  Then your header doesn't contain any `#if` or `#ifdef`, but you incur the cost of a memory allocation.

Comment: How about a conditionally compiled typedef? Is that commonly used? Do you have time to chat or are you busy? Its just I don't want to have a big conversation in the comments box.

Comment: @Ell: the comments box works fine - I've seen these things go 100+ comments in length.  A conditionally compiled typedef could work, but in the end, you would have to have some `#if` or `#ifdef` around it to make sure it compiles to the right type which would be visible to everyone, so you won't get much 'cleaner' code.

Comment: Okay I’ve decided on using `#ifdef`'s for the includes and using cmake to decide which source file. Thank you very much for your guidance! :)

Answer (score 6):

Starting from the end, yes, truly a horrible idea, as are most ideas that start with "I want to avoid the cost of virtual functions".

As to why you're getting the segmentation fault (stack overflow specifically), it's because you aren't using virtual functions, but static linking. The compiler doesn't know that `mImplementation` is anything but a `PlatformIndependantClass`, so when you try to call `return mImplementation->GetPlatformName()` you're calling the same function over and over.

What you achieved is called *shadowing*, you're using compile-time function resolution. The compiler will call the `GetPlatformName` function *of the actual type of the variable you're calling it from*, since there's no virtual table to overwrite the pointers to the actual functions. Since `mImplementation` is `PlatformIndependantClass`, `mImplementation->GetPlatformName` will always be `PlatformIndependantClass::GetPlatformName`.

Edit: Of course the question of why you need to create both a Windows and a Linux copy of your engine at the same time comes to mind. You'll never use both of them at the same time, right?

So why not just have two different libraries, one for each system, and link the right one from your makefile. You get the best of all worlds!

Comment: The explanation of the segfault was very useful, I don't know why I didn't realize that! But I think I will go for a different approach on the cross platform code although thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the constructor to build the platform-specific instance, I would create a static factory method to create the instances:

```
PlatformIndependantClass* PlatformIndependantClass::getPlatformIndependantClass() {
    #ifdef TARGET_LINUX
        return new LinuxClass();
    #endif
    #ifdef TARGET_WINDOWS
        return new WindowsClass();
    #endif
}
```

This way you avoid the recursion, and you also don't need your mImplementation pointer.

I would also try to avoid platform-specific classes, but that's another story :)

Comment: This was one of my initial ideas, and one I might end up going with, I just don't like the fact that there is an explicit function, I guess what I was trying to do was make an... implicit factory using the constructor (if that made any sense to you)

Comment: Except without a virtual table, you still can't get virtual calls.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to have polymorphic behavior without any run-time overhead, you can try the [curiously recurring template pattern (CRTP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). The base class is a template, and the derived class uses itself as the template parameter for the base. This requires your classes to be defined as templates, which further restricts them to be implemented completely in the header (.hpp) files.

I'm not sure how to apply the pattern in your particular case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the constructor is causing the infinite recursion.  It's the GetPlatformName() function.  Because it's not set as virtual, it can only call itself.

Two solutions: Make that function virtual, or do away with the inheritance completely.

Either way, the cost of a function only calling another function will be more expensive than using virtual functions in the first place.  So I would say keep the inheritance, and virtualize  the functions specific to the platform, and call them directly, without going through a base class function.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct about the infinte loop.  The fix is actually easier than you'd think.

PlatformIndependantClass.hpp

```
#include //portable headers
struct PlatformDependantClass; //defined in Cpp file
class PlatformIndependantClass {
    public:
        PlatformIndependantClass();
        ~PlatformIndependantClass();
        std::string GetPlatformName();
    private:
        std::unique_ptr<PlatformDependantClass> mImplementation; //note, different type

};
```

LinuxClass.cpp

```
#ifdef __GNUC__ 
#include //linux headers
#include "PlatformIndependantClass.hpp"
struct PlatformDependantClass { //linux only stuff
     //stuff
};    

PlatformIndependantClass() {
    mImplementation.reset(new PlatformDependantClass );
}
~PlatformIndependantClass() {
}
std::string PlatformIndependantClass::GetPlatformName() {
    return std::string("This was compiled on linux!");
}
#endif //__GNUC__
```

WindowsClass.cpp

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#include //windows headers
#include "PlatformIndependantClass.hpp"
struct PlatformDependantClass {  //windows only stuff
     //stuff
};    

PlatformIndependantClass() {
    mImplementation.reset(new PlatformDependantClass );
}
~PlatformIndependantClass() {
}
std::string PlatformIndependantClass::GetPlatformName() {
    return std::string("This was compiled on Windows!");
}
#endif //_MSC_VER
```

There's only *ONE* class defined here.  In windows, it only compiles and contains windows stuff, and in Linux, it only compiles and contains linux stuff.  Note that the `void*` thing is called an "Opaque pointer" or "pimpl idiom" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer

Comment: -1, How is making the pointer a `void *` "the easy fix"? `delete mImplementation` is not even going to compile, nor will your class function redefinitions...

Comment: I noticed and corrected it right before you commented actually.  I could have sworn I've seen pImpl with a void*, but I had done it wrong, and I corrected myself from the wiki link I put in.